# Clone repository as background process with &

Tags: linux, git, process, background, clone

Why can't I run git clone in the background. Is this a downloading limitation or a git limitation or something else completely?

```
git clone <repository> &
```

Comment: I guess git doesn't support automatically because there is no clean way of doing it. Git is not a service and if it does it in the background there is no way of knowing when the cloning process is completed (you can see what is happening with help of ps though)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work just fine. However, you should be aware that "in the background" doesn't mean "where I can't see it". The command may still output data to the screen (which git certainly does), overwriting whatever you're currently doing. This is purely cosmetic.

To run it in the background without anything showing on screen, you can redirect its output to `/dev/null`:

```
git clone yourrepo > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

If you want to be able to inspect the output later, replace `/dev/null` with `mylogfile.txt`

Comment: Thank you for your answer and correcting my understanding of in the background vs. no output.